# Conditionally Include() in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I'm using EF4.3 with DbContext.

I have an entity that I store in cache, so I need to eager load the necessary data before converting to a list and popping it in cache.

My database is normalised so data is spread over several tables. The base entity is "User", a User may or may not be a "Subscriber" and a Subscriber can be one of 3 types "Contributor", "Member" or "Administrator"

At present the whole fetch is not very elegant due to my lack of knowledge in EF, Linq et al.

```
    public static User Get(Guid userId)
    {
        Guard.ThrowIfDefault(userId, "userId");

        var r = new CrudRepo<User>(Local.Items.Uow.Context);

        var u = r.FindBy(x => x.UserId == userId)
            .Include("BookmarkedDeals")
            .Include("BookmarkedStores")
            .SingleOrDefault();

        if (u.IsNotNull() && u.IsActive)
        {
            if (u.IsAdmin)
            {
                u.GetAdministrator();
            }
            else if (u.IsContributor)
            {
                u.GetContributor();
            }
            else if (u.IsMember)
            {
                u.GetMember();
            }
            else
            {
                string.Format("Case {0} not implemented", u.UserRoleId)
                    .Throw<NotImplementedException>();
            }
        }

        return u;
    }
```

Each of the 'Get' methods gets a Subscriber entity plus the relevant Include() entities for the role type.

I'm pretty sure it can be done a whole lot more elegently than this but struggling with the initial thought process.

Anyone help?

UPDATED with example of one of the Get methods

```
    public static void GetMember(this User user)
    {
        Guard.ThrowIfNull(user, "user");

        var r = new ReadRepo<Subscriber>(Local.Items.Uow.Context);

        user.Subscriber = r.FindBy(x => x.UserId == user.UserId)
            .Include("Kudos")
            .Include("Member.DrawEntries")
            .Include("Member.FavouriteCategories")
            .Include("Member.FavouriteStores")
            .Single();
    }
```

Comment: Personally, I don't mind this. I don't know how much I like the methods on the entities that can get other entities. I wouldn't personally do that because I like my entities pure and clean data stores. I'm not writing this as an answer because this is opinion. I think if it works for you, and its readable, its fine. I always work with this in mind: Change your functional code AS NEEDED. Not just because you think it looks ugly? There is always bigger fish to fry out there.

Comment: Could you show one of the "Get..." method what they do exactly?

Comment: @Slauma Added an example

Comment: @RyanBennett The reason I call one from the other is that they are actually a single entity - a "user". It's only normalisation of the db tables that makes them separate.

Comment: Imho your code is fine for this situation. I don't think that you can compress this into a single database query. But maybe someone else has an idea (perhaps using a projection instead of Include).

Comment: My opinion is that this is perfectly acceptable. If you really want to clean up the code (not that it's bad) you could go with a factory pattern. A factory with a Create / Query method. The factory can then create or read an administrator, contributor or member. I am with Ryan though: there are likely to be more important things to worry about.

Answer (score 0):

If your "User" entity is connected to your other entities you can use the Load method of the connected entity collection to get the related entities. For example if your "User" entity has a property "Subscriber" you could call u.Subscriber.Load() to get the related entity. Here is the related [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896376.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
var u = r.FindBy(x => x.UserId == userId)
        .Include("BookmarkedDeals")
        .Include("BookmarkedStores")
        .SingleOrDefault();

if(someCondition)
{
    u = u.Include("something");
}
```

Don't have a place to test this, but have you tried that?